# Find exactly equal rows in 2 tables, both in terms of value and number

Tags: sql, join

I have two Table, that both of them have 2 field (provinceid,cityid)
i want to find provinceid that have exactly the same cityid in this two table.
for example i have this tables:

table1:

| provinceid | cityid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |

table2:

| provinceid | cityid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |

i want a query that just return provinceid =2 and city id =3 and 4.
i try this query and it is right. but i want a better query:

```
select provinceid ,t1.cityid
from t1 
left join t2 on t1=provinceid=t2.provinceid and t1.cityid=t2.cityid
where t2.provinceid is not null and t2.cityid is not null
and t1.provinceid not in (select provinceid 
from t2 
left join t1 on t1=provinceid=t2.provinceid and t1.cityid=t2.cityid
where t1.provinceid is not null and t1.cityid is not null)
```

thank you

Comment: you `don't need a left join` if you want only the `matching entries` from both the tables

Comment: Please tag your specific database. Is there any reason you did not accept an answer to your previous question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select t1.provinceid ,t1.cityid 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 
    on t1.provinceid=t2.provinceid 
    and t1.cityid=t2.cityid
    and t1.provinceid in (
        select distinct(t1.provinceid)
        from 
            (select provinceid, count(provinceid) as cnt from table1 group by provinceid) as t1
        cross join 
            (select provinceid ,count(provinceid) as cnt from table2 group by provinceid) as t2
        where t1.cnt = t2.cnt);
```

Output:

| provinceid | cityid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

Comment: if i use this query , it retrieves provinceid=3 ,cityid=6 and i dont want this. i just want equal rows, Both in terms of value and number

Comment: As per your example table `provinceid=3 ,cityid=6 ` is present in both the tables so why not ?

Comment: cause i want exactly equal rows in both tables

Comment: all the records are equal. do you mean the row count of the selected id should be the same in both the tables ?

Comment: @sab, Updated my answer based on your clarification. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Besides match in provid and cityid, we are looking for exactly matching sets of records as well. There might be many different methods to this. I prefer to have string comparison for list of cities for each provide with addition to provide and cityid match clause to remove other sets of provide and cityid which are available in tables but not the exact row match.

```
WITH table1 AS(
SELECT 1 AS PROVID, 1 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS PROVID, 2 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS PROVID, 3 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS PROVID, 4 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS PROVID, 6 AS CITYID FROM DUAL 
),
table2 AS (
SELECT 1 AS PROVID, 1 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS PROVID, 5 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS PROVID, 3 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS PROVID, 4 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS PROVID, 6 AS CITYID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS PROVID, 7 AS CITYID FROM DUAL
),
listed_table1 AS (
SELECT 
    a.provid, 
    listagg(cityid,',') within GROUP (ORDER BY cityid) list_city 
FROM table1 a 
GROUP BY a.provid
),
listed_table2 AS (
SELECT 
    a.provid, 
    listagg(cityid,',') within GROUP (ORDER BY cityid) list_city 
FROM table2 a 
GROUP BY a.provid
)
SELECT 
   t1.provid, t1.cityid 
FROM 
    (SELECT x.*, x1.list_city FROM table1 x, listed_table1 x1 WHERE x.provid = x1.provid) t1,
    (SELECT y.*, y1.list_city FROM table2 y, listed_table2 y1 WHERE y.provid = y1.provid) t2
WHERE t1.provid = t2.provid AND t1.cityid = t2.cityid AND t1.list_city = t2.list_city
;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I have added comments to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but whay did you join table 1 with listed_table 1 , and table 2 with listed_table2? why did not you just join listed_table1 with listed_table 2?

Comment: @sab - the listed_tables1 and 2 do not have a separate city ID column. They are converted into a comma-separated group. If that works for you then no need to join table1 with listed_table1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(union ..)except (inner join..)` to detect non-matches. Step by step

```
with u12 as (
  select PROVID, CITYID from table1
  union  
  select PROVID, CITYID from table2
),
c12 as (
  select t1.PROVID, t2.CITYID   
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.PROVID=t2.PROVID and t1.CITYID=t2.CITYID
),
nonMatch as (
  select distinct PROVID
  from (
     select PROVID,  CITYID from u12
     except
     select PROVID,  CITYID from c12
  ) t
)
select * 
from table1 t
where not exists (
         select 1 
         from nonMatch n
         where n.PROVID = t.PROVID);
```

If a number of doubles counts then count them first

```
with t1 as (
  select PROVID, CITYID, count(*) n
  from table1
  group by PROVID, CITYID
),
t2 as (
  select PROVID, CITYID, count(*) n
  from table2
  group by PROVID, CITYID
),
u12 as (
  select PROVID, CITYID, n from t1
  union  
  select PROVID, CITYID, n from t2
),
c12 as (
  select t1.PROVID, t1.CITYID, t1.n   
  from t1
  join t2 on t1.PROVID = t2.PROVID and t1.CITYID = t2.CITYID and t1.n = t2.n
),
nonMatch as (
  select distinct PROVID
  from (
     select PROVID, CITYID, n from u12
     except
     select PROVID, CITYID, n from c12
  ) t
)
select * 
from table1 t
where not exists (
         select 1 
         from nonMatch n
         where n.PROVID = t.PROVID)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3e25367ece1e70a744380195c12f29e)

Comment: Thank You , but this Query does not consider equal number of cities that belong to a province

Comment: Do you mean doubles are allowed and should be counted by the query? For example regarding provinceid=1 table1 contains two rows `(1,2) (1,2)`  while  table2 contains only one `(1,2)` row. Thus provinceid=1 must be excluded from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method for an exact match is to use string aggregation.  The exact syntax varies by database, but in Standard SQL this looks like:

```
select t1.provinceid, t2.provinceid
from (select provinceid,
             listagg(cityid, ',') within group (order by cityid) as cities
      from t1
      group by provinceid
     ) t1 join
     (select provinceid,
             listagg(cityid, ',') within group (order by cityid) as cities
      from t2
      group by provinceid
     ) t2
     on t1.cities = t2.cities;
```

If you want the `provinceid`s to be the same as well, just add `t1.provinceid = t2.provinceid` to the `on` clause.

Or, if you want the `provinceid`s to be the same, you can use `full join` instead:

```
select provinceid
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (provinceid, cityid)
group by provinceid
having count(*) = count(t1.cityid) and count(*) = count(t2.cityid);
```